# JSON link from google developer tools not working in Python (or in browser)

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, data-science, data-extraction

I am trying to extract the data in the table at **https://www.ecoregistry.io/emit-certifications/ra/10**

Using the google developer tools>network tab, I am able to get the json link where the data for this table is stored: **https://api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications**

I am able to manually copy this json data and extract the information using this code I've written:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = '''PASTE JSON DATA HERE'''
info = json.loads(data)
columns = ['# Certificate', 'Carbon offsets destination', 'Final user', 'Taxpayer subject','Date','Tons delivered']
dat = list()
for x in info['emitcertifications']:
dat.append([x['consecutive'],x['reasonUsingCarbonOffsets'],x['userEnd'],x['passiveSubject'],x['date'],x['quantity']])
df = pd.DataFrame(dat,columns=columns)
df.to_csv('Data.csv')
```

I want to automate it such that I can extract the data from the json link: **https://api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications** directly instead of manually pasting json data in:

```
data = '''PASTE JSON DATA HERE'''
```

The link is not working in python or even in browser directly:

```
import requests
import json
url = ('https://api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications')
response = requests.get(url)
print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```

The error output I get is:
{'status': 0, 'codeMessages': [{'codeMessage': 'ERROR_401', 'param': 'invalid', 'message': 'No autorizado'}]}

When I download the data from the developer tools then this dictionary has 'status':1 and after that all the data is there.

Edit: I tried adding request headers to the url but it still did not work:

```
import requests
import json
url = ('https://api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications')
hdrs = {"accept": "application/json","accept-language": "en-IN,en;q=0.9,hi-IN;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5","authorization": "Bearer null", "content-type": "application/json","if-none-match": "W/\"1326f-t9xxnBEIbEANJdito3ai64aPjqA\"", "lng": "en", "platform": "ecoregistry","sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"100\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"100\"", "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0", "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"", "sec-fetch-dest": "empty","sec-fetch-mode": "cors", "sec-fetch-site": "same-site" }
response = requests.get(url, headers = hdrs)
print(response)
info = response.json()
print(json.dumps(info, indent=4))
```

print(response) give output as '<Response [304]>' while info = response.json() gives traceback error 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error? Did you send the authorization tokens in order to authenticate against the server?

Comment: I am using requests.get(url) to get the json...the error i get is error 401.

Comment: @Sr.S I have added the error I am getting to the question

Comment: Yeah, you are not sending authorization tokens, if your're checking from a browser, open development tools, check the request sent to the server and the tokens in the headers

Comment: @Sr.S I added the request headers to the url. But it is still not working. I have updated the question with the error I am getting now.

Comment: Did you remove the Bearer token for security, or you sent "null" as token? Bearer tokens should look like AbCdEf123456

Comment: @Sr.S The request header has 'authorization' value set to 'Bearer null'. The only thing which resembles AbCdEf123456 is the 'If-None-Match' value: W/"1326f-t9xxnBEIbEANJdito3ai64aPjqA"

Comment: And the browser works? Try to replace null with that token, but seems really weird that the request sent from your browser uses null.

Comment: @Sr.S not working :( . Yeah, weird. This link (https://api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications) does not even open in the browser. Only able to access data in it when you go the network tab in developer options for the main page link ( https://www.ecoregistry.io/emit-certifications/ra/10)

Comment: You want to automate the click on "see certificate" from that page? I'm not able to retrieve any json, just a pdf, that's what you want?

Comment: @Sr.S Sorry, did not understand the question. The original page has a table which I want ( ecoregistry.io/emit-certifications/ra/10). The data for it seems to be coming from JSON at link ((api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications). The data for the latter is available in the developer console, but I am unable to open it in the browser or via python.

Comment: Ok, I've checked the headers, use this as header: {"platform": "ecoregistry"}

Comment: @Sr.S It Is working! Thank you so much! How did you figure out this would be the token?

Comment: Tried every header until got a valid response. If that worked, could you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as an answer:

The headers required for that api in order to retrieve data
is platform: ecoregistry.

```py
import requests as req
import json
req = req.get('https://api-front.ecoregistry.io/api/project/10/emitcertifications', headers={'platform': 'ecoregistry'})
data = json.loads(data)
print(data.keys())
# dict_keys(['status', 'projectSerialYear', 'yearValidation', 'project', 'emitcertifications'])
print(data['emitcertifications'][0].keys())
# dict_keys(['id', 'auth', 'operation', 'typeRemoval', 'consecutive', 'serialInit', 'serialEnd', 'serial', 'passiveSubject', 'passiveSubjectNit', 'isPublicEndUser', 'isAccept', 'isCanceled', 'isCancelProccess', 'isUpdated', 'isKg', 'reasonUsingCarbonOffsetsId', 'reasonUsingCarbonOffsets', 'quantity', 'date', 'nitEnd', 'userEnd'])
```